# How can I create a character variable in a SAS macro?

Tags: macros, sas

I am trying to create two variables, one for year, one for month. The year variable is numeric so the code creates it without problem. However, the month variable is character and the code sees it as blank. How can I fix This? Thanks!

```
data sourceh.combined&month.&year.;
set sourceh.count;
ratio=count/total;
month=&month.;
year= &year.;
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would resolve to :

```
month = December;
```

That would be treating the macro variable month as a variable name. To create it as a character variable, you should include it in quotation marks, double quotes so the macro variable resolves.

```
month = "&month";
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried single quotation marks, didn't know I needed double.